# Why does my API Gateway endpoint work in a browser but not in CURL?

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, zsh, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have an API endpoint set up in google cloud platform configured to work with a google cloud function and API Gateway, secured behind an API key. I am attempting to test this and incorporate it into my app, but I'm getting a really weird issue that I'm not sure what's going on.

Before I added the security of the API key I was able to simply run:

`curl https://myendpoint.com/endpoint`

and receive the appropriate response. I'd also get the same response if I put `https://myendpoint.com/endpoint` into a browser URL bar.

However ever since I set up the API key, I am getting a weird issue where when I run curl, following the syntax provided by Google's documentation for using an API key:

`curl https://myendpoint.com/endpoint?key=my_api_key`

My terminal returns the following error:

```
zsh: no matches found: https://myendpoint.com/endpoint?key=my_api_key
```

Now if I run the curl command without the api key i get the correct response that I am unauthorized because I have no key.

But the weirdest part is, that if I copy and paste the URL including the API key into a browser, I get the expected result, and not this "no matches found" error!

So I guess it's something to do with `zsh` or something? or curl specifically? Should I be passing the api key in a different way? maybe in a header?

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with GCP.  zsh is taking the ? to be a wildcard (glob) match, and it's not finding any matches.

You can simply put the whole URL in quotes to stop this globbing behavior:

```
curl "https://myendpoint.com/endpoint?key=my_api_key"
```

Or you can disable globbing in the shell if you don't want it.

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1605802/completely-disable-and-globbing-in-zsh

Comment: Ahhh yes!! That's exactly what it was, thanks so much